# Android Studio error :tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc:313 input->dims->size != 4 (2 != 4) Node number 1 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, inference

I am doing an app in Android Studio that is supposed to classifies a signal
(byte array) following a pathology. I am using a keras model converted into a tflite model and I get that error when I try to do the inference to classify the signals:

> Android Studio error :tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc:313 input->dims->size != 4 (2 != 4) Node number 1 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Bitmap I was generating after applying the Python instance was null. In order to generate a bitmap after a Python instance, we have to generate a byte class array from the Python object.

```
            PyObject pyo = py.getModule("extraccion");
            PyObject object= pyo.callAttr("main", imageString);
            byte [] data =object.toJava(byte[].class);
```

After this, we can convert byte [] data to a Bitmap:

Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp);